How are event handlers with unknown number of parameters done in popular crates?
I'm noticing more and more often that different rust crates use registration of event handlers with any set of parameters the user wants, not the library developer. I have seen this in the following crates: axum, bevy engine, teloxide.
I have a question, how exactly is this done under the hood, how does the library know what parameters the event handler needs, which can have a variable number of parameters, how are they passed to the function? I want to read something on this topic. I can't understand how the library accepts such handler methods in arguments of other methods and no macros are used.

As a trait that is implemented for up to X parameters. Why won't you take a look at the implementation behind those?

I tried, but there is a lot of stuff mixed in there. I would like to see just the basic code somewhere.

How exactly this works depends on the specifics of the library. But the general pattern is to have a trait with a method called with some state, then implement it for every function with up to X parameters (using a macro) when parameters implement some other trait, that signifies the ability to extract the parameter from the state.
For example:
pub struct State {
    // ...
}

pub trait Extractor: Sized {
    fn extract(state: &mut State) -> Self;
}

pub trait Handler<Args> {
    fn call(&mut self, state: &mut State);
}

// The below is usually done with a macro.
impl<F: FnMut()> Handler<()> for F {
    fn call(&mut self, _state: &mut State) {
        self()
    }
}
impl<Arg1: Extractor, F: FnMut(Arg1)> Handler<(Arg1,)> for F {
    fn call(&mut self, state: &mut State) {
        self(Arg1::extract(state))
    }
}
impl<Arg1: Extractor, Arg2: Extractor, F: FnMut(Arg1, Arg2)> Handler<(Arg1, Arg2)> for F {
    fn call(&mut self, state: &mut State) {
        self(Arg1::extract(state), Arg2::extract(state))
    }
}

pub fn call_handler<Args, H: Handler<Args>>(handler: &mut H, state: &mut State) {
    handler.call(state);
}

Type-erasing the handler (for example, in order to store all handlers together) can be done like the following:
pub fn handler_to_dyn<Args, H: Handler<Args> + 'static>(
    mut handler: H,
) -> Box<dyn FnMut(&mut State)> {
    Box::new(move |state| handler.call(state))
}

Although that is often done with an additional trait.

Now I'm confused about the return values from the handlers. I added a trait so that return values can also be selected by library users, but I don't know how to use this new trait in the handlers vector.
I added R generic to all code:
pub trait Handler<Args, R> {
    fn call(&self, state: &mut State) -> R;
}


@JohnDarkman The return value must also be handled uniformly. Commonly, it implements some trait (e.g. IntoResponse) that allows turning it into some common type (Response). In the impl Handler for Fn we transform the return type to Response, and call() returns Response.

Got it all, added another structure to store the result and a trait that converts to that structure, it seems to work. Thanks.
